# Difference between requested and allocated memory - Spark on Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I am running a Spark Job in Kubernetes cluster using spark-submit command as below,

```
bin/spark-submit \
    --master k8s://https://api-server-host:443 \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --name spark-job-name \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=spark \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=docker-repo/pyspark:55 \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark-submit \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.pyspark.pythonVersion=3 \
    --conf spark.executor.memory=4G \
    --files local:///mnt/conf.json \
    local:///mnt/ingest.py
```

and when I check the request and limit for the executor pod, it shows below. There is almost 1700 MB extra got allocated for the pod.

```
Limits:
  memory:  5734Mi
Requests:
  cpu:     4
  memory:  5734Mi
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @CptDolphin 's answer, be aware that Spark *always* allocates [`spark.executor.memoryOverhead`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties) extra memory (max of 10% of `spark.executor.memory` or 384MB, unless explicitly configured), and *may* allocate additional `spark.executor.pyspark.memory` if you defined that in your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

What you define the pod (as individual system) can use is one thing, what you define spark or java or any other app runing inside that system (pod) can use, is another thing; think of it as normal computer with limits, and then your application with its own limits.